Are these superheroes plagiarised?
(Set-up is fictional...)
I run a comic book publishing company and am always on the look-out for new teams of superheroes to feature in one of our strips. This week one of my writers came to me with a suggestion for four 'new' heroes, called PEAR HERALD, BLOND AUREOLE, NEUTRAL POPE DOLL, and GREEN HOOLIGAN CAMEL.
Now, I know this writer - he's a pretty lazy guy and he often does as little as he possibly can to get his job done and sometimes even rehashes other people's material to claim it as his own. So before I sent this idea off to our production team, I called him to my office.
"The thing is," I said to him, "these names... I'm just not completely convinced. It seems like you've just taken the name of a colour and mashed it together with a cool-sounding name to create the finished product..."
At this, he began to fidget and sweat, so I am pretty sure there's something fishy going on here. I just can't quite put my finger on what...
How has the writer derived these names?

@TheEmptyStringPhotographer Why do you assume that this isn't their puzzle? Even if it usually isn't OP's puzzle on this site, Stiv has a lot of reputation, and is likely completely aware of the site guidelines, and probably would have given credit if credit was due.

@Daemons I would assume this comment was meant as a joke because the puzzle asks you to find the proper attribution of these names.

@Daemons it was a joke, hence the quote marks.

Heh, it's hard to tell jokes from serious in comments sometimes :) I myself took a few readings before I was confident which way to take it! Still, hopefully no harm done, and for anyone interested I can confirm that all of the puzzles I post here are my own originals, always have been, and always will :)

The influence is from…

 TEENAGE MUTANT NINJA TURTLES!

Why

 If you look at the super hero names they are the anagrams of the colour of the turtle + their name.


 RED RAPHAEL, BLUE LEONARDO, PURPLE DONATELLO and ORANGE MICHELANGELO



Absolutely right, well found :) Out of interest, what was your break-in? What did you spot first?

@Stiv the anagram tag made me think to use a multi word anagram solver, then I chose the first option to feed into it because it had the least amount of letters. I then used the configurations of 2 words max and 2 letters min. Hoping to find a lead I saw  one of the possible configurations was ‘RAPHAEL RED’ and since I was a big fan of the cartoon growing up and because of the theme of the puzzle I immediately made the connection between it and TMNT, I tried the same logic on the rest and it fit.

Even without seeing the tag, anagrams seemed likely.
